# ffmpeg issues "501 Not Implemented" while recording an RTSP stream

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtsp

I have a 4K camera (Sony SNC-VB770) streaming RTSP.

I'm trying to record the stream into files (each has handy length, say, 1hour)
using a simple script to repeatedly launch ffmpeg (ver 4.1):

```
while : ; do
  # (set $url and $outfile, and then)
  ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -t 3600 -y -i $url -c copy -map 0:0 -b:v 16000k $outfile
done
```

If I run the script on a local PC directly connected to the camera, it works (longer than a week, at least).
However, if I do the same on a server machine located in a data center, it fails randomly with no error message.
Sometimes it runs for a few days, sometimes it dies in one minutes.

Typical output looks like the following:

```
# devname: snc-vb770
# url: rtsp://10.40.35.90/media/video1
# vb: 16000k
# datefmt %d%H
# addtimestamp 0
no timestamp
ffmpeg version 4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/ffmpeg-4.1 --enable-openssl --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-shared --enable-libx264 --enable-libvorbis --enable-filter=drawtext --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-fontconfig
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://10.40.35.90/media/video1':
  Metadata:
    title           : Sony RTSP Server
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.066667, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 14.99 fps, 14.99 tbr, 90k tbn, 29.97 tbc
Output #0, mp4, to './2811.mp4':
  Metadata:
    title           : Sony RTSP Server
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 16000 kb/s, 14.99 fps, 14.99 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mp4 @ 0x24e4ec0] Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0. This is deprecated and will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the timestamps properly
[mp4 @ 0x24e4ec0] pts has no value
[mp4 @ 0x24e4ec0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 0, current: 0; changing to 1. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
frame=   33 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=    1792kB time=00:00:02.00 bitrate=7332.9kbits/s speed=3.57x
...
frame=  104 fps=8.4 q=-1.0 Lsize=    6532kB time=00:00:06.74 bitrate=7939.6kbits/s speed=0.548x
video:6531kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.023506%
```

I've looked into RTSP packet and found an "RTSP/1.0 501 Not Implemented" is sent from ffmpeg to the camera.
After that the camera eventually sent back "RTSP/1.0 505 RTSP Version not supported" and then ffmpeg quits shortly.

The "501" packet seems to be generated by libavformat/rtsp.c:ff_rtsp_read_reply(),
when ffmpeg receive a malformed RTSP packet with method=(null), status_code=0.
I don't know why such packets arrive at random timing and who is wrong (maybe the camera, maybe any of network switches or routers in the middle of the network path from the camera to the server machine).
But anyway, I don't want the recording to be stopped
due to those malformed packets.

Is there any workaround to make ffmpeg ignore invalid RTSP packets and just continue the recording?

Additional information:

- I've tested the recording with both ffmpeg ver4.1 and 2.8.4 and no difference observed.
- No difference observed at lower resolution nor at lower bitrate.
- I have 3 cameras from various manufacturers in the same network environment.
  All of the three are working without problem for more than a month.
  Only the Sony SNC-VB770 shows the strange behavior.

Comment: Sounds like possible bug in camera firmware to me.

Comment: Yes, I think so, too. I've reported this issue to the vendor and waiting for the reply.
Meanwhile looking for any workaround to skip the wrong packets.

Comment: If your do while loop works as intended, then you could use an output like mpegts that supports chunking the video into named segments. That way if you have a network blip or firmware issue at most you would miss a few seconds of footage.

Comment: Thanks for a practical suggestion! I'll do that if I cannot hear any good news from the vendor within a reasonable period of time.

Comment: @atsushi, any update on this issue?

Comment: The vendor looked into the problem and found possible root cause. However they did not fix it yet. I can imagine it is not easy to fix since it can take rather long time (order of a few weeks) to reproduce the issue.

For now the recording process is on going with the workaround suggested by theUser in the previous comment.